# No method txtUserName_Completed with correct signature found on type - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am getting "No method txtUserName_Completed with correct signature found on type" after moving to VS2022. Not sure how to fix it. Removing "Completed" throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. Restarted VS, cleaned solution, deleted bin and obj folders.
It breaks here at "LoadFromXaml" line in xaml.g.cs:

```
    private void InitializeComponent() 
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));
    loginPage = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage>(this, "loginPage");
    txtUserName = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "txtUserName");
    txtPassword = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "txtPassword");   
}
```

Xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MobileApp.UI.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Common.Converters;assembly=Xamarin.Common"            
             xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Common.Localization;assembly=Xamarin.Common"
             x:Name="loginPage"
             x:Class="MobileApp.UI.Views.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vms:LoginViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout>
                <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,75,0,0">
                       
                        <Entry x:Name="txtUserName" Text="{Binding UserName}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={converters:InvertedBooleanConverter}}" WidthRequest="250" Placeholder="Username" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" PlaceholderColor="#999999" Margin="15" TextColor="Black" Completed="txtUserName_Completed"/>
                        <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Text="{Binding Password}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={converters:InvertedBooleanConverter}}" WidthRequest="250" Placeholder="Password" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" PlaceholderColor="#999999" Margin="15" TextColor="Black" IsPassword="True" Completed="txtPassword_Completed"/>
                        <Button Text="{i18n:Translate Login}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={converters:InvertedBooleanConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource FontButton}" TextColor="White" Margin="15" BackgroundColor="#0b8442" FontSize="Medium" />

                        <Button Text="{i18n:Translate Contact_Us}" Style="{DynamicResource FontButton}"  TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#0b8442" FontSize="Medium" Margin="15" Command="{Binding ContactUsCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={converters:InvertedBooleanConverter}}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="#d9d9d9" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"/>

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind:

```
using MobileApp.UI.ViewModels;
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileApp.UI.Views
{
    //[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        private InvoicesViewModel CurrentContext { get { return (InvoicesViewModel)BindingContext; } }
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
        public void txtUserName_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChkIfCanLogin();
        }

        public void txtPassword_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChkIfCanLogin();
        }        

        public void ChkIfCanLogin()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUserName.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                var loginViewModel = this.BindingContext as LoginViewModel;
                loginViewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the events and their handlers, rebuild, then re-add them and rebuild

Comment: @Jason tried that getting same error message.

Comment: 1. I notice you've commented out the `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in the Code Behind, try to uncomment it and clean the bin and obj folders of both the shared project and each platform project, then rebuild your project.  2.I cannot reproduce the issue on my side, could the project build successfully if removing all the `Entry` ?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT tried your suggestion. Removing all "Entry" causing "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
" at this line "global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));"

Comment: You may need create a new project and add the relevant code to debug which part goes wrong as I cannot reproduce the issue on my side.